# Parallel merge strategy without deadlock

Tags: sql-server, merge, sql-server-2016, database-deadlocks

Using SQL Server 2016, I wish to merge data from a `SourceTable` to a `DestinationTable` with a simple procedure containing a simple insert/update/delete on the same table.

The `SourceTable` is filled by several different applications, and they call the `MergeOrders` stored procedure to merge their uploaded rows from `SourceTable` into `DestinationTable`.

There can be several instances of `MergeOrders` stored procedure running in parallel.

I get a lot of lock, but that's normal, the issue is that sometimes I get "RowGroup deadlocks", which I cannot afford.

What is the best way to execute such merge operation in this parallel environment.

I am thinking about TABLOCK or SERIALIZABLE hints, or maybe application locks to serialize the access, but interested if there is better way.

Comment: Do you have any other indexes on the DestinationTable?  If all the apps use a single SourceTable, there's probably no point in running this in parallel, and an application lock is the simplest approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An app lock will serialize sessions attempting to run this procedure.  It should look like this:

```
create or alter procedure ProcWithAppLock 
with execute as owner
as
begin
  set xact_abort on;
  set nocount on;
  begin transaction;
  declare @lockName nvarchar(255) = object_name(@@procid) + '-applock';
  exec sp_getapplock @lockName,'Exclusive','Transaction',null,'dbo';


  --do stuff
  waitfor delay '00:00:10';
  select getdate() dt, object_name(@@procid);

  exec sp_releaseapplock @lockName, 'Transaction', 'dbo';
  commit transaction;
end
```

There are a couple of subtle things in this template.  First off it doesn't have a catch block, and relies on xact_abort to release the applock in case of an error.  And you want to explicitly release the app lock in case this procedure is called in the context of a longer-running transaction.  And finally the principal for the lock is set to `dbo` so that no non-dbo user can acquire a conflicting lock.  This also requires that the procedure be run with `execute as owner`, as the application user would not normally be `dbo`.

Comment: Thank you. My original sp already uses XACT_ABORT ON, but also has a CATCH block to do various logging. Will it cause any malfunction? I guess i will just try.

Comment: Nope, that should be fine.  This doesn't use TRY/CATCH just to make it a bit simpler.

Comment: You mentioned I should release the lock manually, if the sp is longer running (which is the case). Should I release manually the lock in the CATCH section as well then?

Comment: No need to release the lock manually in CATCH if you're forcing a rollback.